# Is it possible to search by value in an array of json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Lets say I have this json array stored in a dynamic newtonsoft json object:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Amal",
      "Country":"India"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Luke",
      "Country":"England"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Tom",
      "Country":"Australia"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Ram",
      "Country":"India"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Jane",
      "Country":"France"
   }
]
```

I need to be able to return the json objects in the array where a name ends with an "e"

Looking for these results:

```
 [{ "Name":"Luke", "Country":"England" }, { "Name":"Jane", "Country":"France" }]
```

Comment: Do you know how to parse a Json string with c#, or how to do list processing? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! This can be done (more than a few ways), can you update your post to include what you have tried and what isn't working please?

Comment: Its also possible to create a class, in case later you would like to use, just deserialize into that class

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use `Linq` extensions and  `Value<string>()` method of the `JToken` since `JArray` is a collection of `JToken`s. Then build a new `JArray` with filtered tokens.

```
var json = "[ { \"Name\":\"Amal\", \"Country\":\"India\" }, { \"Name\":\"Luke\", \"Country\":\"England\" }, { \"Name\":\"Tom\", \"Country\":\"Australia\" }, { \"Name\":\"Ram\", \"Country\":\"India\" }, { \"Name\":\"Jane\", \"Country\":\"France\" }]";
var arr = JArray.Parse(json);       
var result = new JArray( arr.Where(r=> r.Value<string>("Name").EndsWith("e")));
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dRhq0T)